# Conditional insertion of row using data.table or dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a data.table like this:

```
w <- data.table(id=c(rep(1:2,each=4)),
                b=c(rep(1:4,each=1)),
                c1=c(letters[1:8]),
                d=c(LETTERS[1:8]))
```

Now, I´d like to:

1. for each id with b >2
2. have c1 equal to lag c1
3. have d equal to lead d (or NA)
4. b should be NA

The desired output is:

```
  > w2
    id  b c1  d
 1:  1  1  a  A
 2:  1  2  b  B
 3:  1  3  c  C
 4:  1 NA  b  D
 5:  1  4  d  D
 6:  1 NA  c NA
 7:  2  1  a  A
 8:  2  2  b  B
 9:  2  3  c  C
10:  2 NA  b  D
11:  2  4  d  D
12:  2 NA  c NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could summarise the *data.table* such as described in your question and then add that to the original *data.table* with `rbindlist`.

Using:

```
# option 1:
w.add <- w[, .(b = NA^(b > 2), 
               c1 = shift(c1, fill = NA, type = 'lag'), 
               d = shift(d, fill = NA, type = 'lead')), 
           id][is.na(b)]

# option 2:
w.add <- w[, .(b = NA^(b > 2)[b > 2], 
               c1 = shift(c1, fill = NA, type = 'lag')[b > 2], 
               d = shift(d, fill = NA, type = 'lead')[b > 2]), 
           id]

rbindlist(list(w, w.add))[order(id)]
```

gives:

```
    id  b c1  d
 1:  1  1  a  A
 2:  1  2  b  B
 3:  1  3  c  C
 4:  1  4  d  D
 5:  1 NA  b  D
 6:  1 NA  c NA
 7:  2  1  e  E
 8:  2  2  f  F
 9:  2  3  g  G
10:  2  4  h  H
11:  2 NA  f  H
12:  2 NA  g NA
```